# Two jquery pagination plugin in the same page doesn't seem to work

Tags: jquery, plugins, pagination, jquery-pagination

I use jquery pagination plugin for paging... If there is one pagination plugin there is no problem for me... But if there is two one seems to work but the other doesn't seem too... Here is my code,

```
<div id="PagerUp" class="pager">

</div><br /><br /><br />
    <div id="ResultsDiv">

</div>
<div id="PagerDown" class="pager">

</div>
```

And my jquery has,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         var itemsPerPage = 5;
         $(document).ready(function() {
             getRecordspage(0, itemsPerPage);
             var maxvalues = $("#HfId").val();
             $(".pager").pagination(maxvalues, {
                 callback: getRecordspage,
                 current_page: 0,
                 items_per_page: itemsPerPage,
                 num_display_entries: 5,
                 next_text: 'Next',
                 prev_text: 'Prev',
                 num_edge_entries: 1
             });
         });

</script>
```

Here is what i am getting...

[alt text http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/5618/pagerse.jpg](http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/5618/pagerse.jpg)

Both works but Look at the `pagerup` the selected page is `3` but the `PagerDown` shows `1`.... How to change one pager on other pagers callback event in jquery....

**EDIT:**
using mef's idea doesn't seem to work...

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Main.css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/jquery.pagination.js">
      </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".pager").pagination(300, { callback: pagecallback,
                current_page: 0,
                items_per_page: 5,
                num_display_entries: 5,
                next_text: 'Next',
                prev_text: 'Prev',
                num_edge_entries: 1
            });
        });
    function pagecallback() {
        var paginationClone = $("#Pagination > *").clone(true);
        $("#Pagination2").empty();
        paginationClone.appendTo("#Pagination2");
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

<div class="pager" id="pagination">
  <!-- the container for your first pagination area -->
</div>

<div id="results">
  <!-- the container where you show your results -->
</div>

<div class="pager" id="Pagination2">
  <!-- the container for your second pagination area -->
</div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since this doesn't seem to be officially supported, here is a workaround ([**working demo**](http://jsbin.com/emovo)).

**Step 1** 
Create your HTML markup as follows:

```
<div class="pagination" id="Pagination">
  <!-- the container for your first pagination area -->
</div>

<div id="results">
  <!-- the container where you show your results -->
</div>

<div class="pagination" id="Pagination2">
  <!-- the container for your second pagination area -->
</div>
```

**Step 2** The idea:
The idea is now to use the pagination plugin **as usual** with the first pagination div. But additionally, we want to copy all contents of the first pagination div to the second pagination div every time a page change occurs.

**Step 3** Tweak the pageSelect-callback:
Add the following lines at the end of your callback function:

```
var paginationClone = $("#Pagination > *").clone(true);
$("#Pagination2").empty();
paginationClone.appendTo("#Pagination2");
```

It is very important to include the boolean parameter (`withDataAndEvents`) with the `.clone` call, otherwise the copy of your pagination won't have any click events.

Now, every time you click on a pagination element (regardless if it is the original or the copy), the page will change and the pagination elements will update accordingly.

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur: I added a demo link - it works. There is a typo in your first pagination id.

Comment: @Mef brilliant... `Clone` really works man... Its people like you make this forum so special...

Comment: @Mef if possible suggest me an answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591295/jquery-image-preview-plugin-issue

Comment: There's a related question asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871357/two-jquery-pagination-plugin-in-the-same-page#13871357

Answer (score 2):

Probably this is not the answer you were hoping for, but there's a feature request for the jQuery Pagination plugin that suggest that having two pagers on the same page is not supported by the current implementation:

http://plugins.jquery.com/node/11825