# Does anyone know how to use or modify jQuery Pagination plugin to show nav on top and bottom of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, pagination, jquery-pagination

I am working with http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination and want to have the pagination applied to both top and bottom of the page. Is there any way to make this happen?

**Edit - Solution Full Code**

```
$("#pagination").pagination(data, {
    num_edge_entries: 2, 
    num_display_entries: 8,
    items_per_page: 5,
    next_show_always: false, 
    prev_show_always: false,

    callback: function(page_index, jp){
            $.get("ajax.php?n="+page_index, function(data){
                $("#content").empty().append(data);
            });
        }

        var paginationClone = $("#pagination > *").clone(true);
        $("#paginationbottom").empty();
        paginationClone.appendTo("#paginationbottom");                
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

A possible workaround is at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605053/two-jquery-pagination-plugin-in-the-same-page-doesnt-seem-to-work/2621617#2621617).

Essentially tweak the callback to clone one paginator to the other.

---

Ability to do this is apparently a ["critical" feature request](http://plugins.jquery.com/node/11825).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but here is how I was able to implement paging at the top and bottom of the content.  Hope this helps someone that may be looking for this answer.

**In the HTML I added a second pagnation holder like this:**

```
<div id="pagnationNav1" class="holder"></div>
<div id="itemContainer">

    ''' Your looping code goes here

</div>
<div id="pagnationNav2" class="holder"></div>
```