# Jquery Pagination Plugin

Tags: jquery, pagination

Good morning Brian,

Your work on using the slice() method to get jquery's pagination plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination) is fantastic and was so helpful.
I'm wondering if you have implemented the jquery plugin so that the Pagination div is on the top and the bottom of the div where the pagination results are displayed.

I did not have success using the clone() method... so I'm wondering what I need to do.
Your help is greatly, greatly appreciated.

corey

Comment: Who is Brian? are you referring your question to someone specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Just call the pagination function with both destination divs:

```
$("#top-Pagination, #bottom-pagination").pagination(/* parameters */);
```

Or:

```
$("#top-Pagination").pagination(/* parameters */);
$("#bottom-Pagination").pagination(/* parameters */);
```

Comment: I did do that.  However, the end result I'm looking for is that the two pagination divs agree - meaning that if you navigate the top one to the 3rd "page", the bottom one reflects that also.  

I already tried your suggestion but if the top nav is on the 3rd page the bottom nav still shows the first.

Comment: Ah, in that case, maybe you can explain why clone isn't working?  There are multiple SO answers that use clone to achieve what you're trying to do, and they seem to have worked... For instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209152/does-anyone-know-how-to-use-or-modify-jquery-pagination-plugin-to-show-nav-on-top